# Rampart 1.6.2 Error loading crypto properties

Tags: cryptography, rampart

Axis2 1.6.3 Rampart 1.6.2 possible bug

Working with Rampart 1.6.2 and axis2 1.6.3 I found that when try to create keystore from a p12 read from local disk the system go on error

ERROR (org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil:349) - Error loading crypto properties.
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot create instance

I try to debug the library with source and I found that it was very abnormal.

After I try to run Merlin with same parameter and go.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CredentialException;
import org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin;
public class TestMerlin {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Merlin merlin = new Merlin();
    String storepass = "correctpassword"; 
    String provider = null;
    String type = "PKCS12";
    try {
      ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
      String cert = "C:/cert/certificato.p12";
      InputStream input = merlin.loadInputStream(loader,cert);
      KeyStore ks = merlin.load(input, storepass, provider, type);
    } catch (CredentialException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("end");
  }
}
```

Finally I download the previous version of Rampart the 1.6.1 and it go, but there are many lib incompatibylity.

Comment: I don't think the `cert` variable should be a full path name, class loaders are usually used with resources, which are loaded the same way as classes.

Comment: the cert variable is a full path name and the TestMerlin run correctly, and the certificate is load into keystore.